# Pattern matching in a flash video game and send mouse click into that region in linux

Tags: c, linux, automation, pattern-matching, screenshot

I'm trying to make an automation tool to play a flash game or a video game for the purpose of learning. I found that in Windows we can use AutoIT to locate a specific region on the screen and immediately send a mouse click into that region. However, I'm haven't found anything similar in Linux, probably this can all be done at the lower level. Can anyone show me some ideas how I can do this (find a pattern on the screen and mouse click into that) in Linux? I heart that there is some Java package named awt.robot that can do this and be platform independent, but I prefer doing it in C or C++.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use xdotool in Linux for moving mouse cursor, mouse click and typing. I use it and it works fine.

awt.robot seem to do the same thing,

I have not found anything for pattern matching unfortunately.  I checked AutoIT website but they do not say anything about pattern maching.